# NSTextField Scroll

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, rss, nsstring

I'm relatively new (but not a beginner) to Obj-C and Xcode. I'm building a Mac app that requires a ticker-like RSS feed. I know this requires a label as the outlet and the NSString for the label needs to be from the RSS feed's URL, but how do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

For a beginner, this could be pretty hard to solve.

I would use an existing library like https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/mktickerview

Hope that helps :)